# AWS Web Application and Emails

Tags: email, web-applications, amazon-web-services

I have a web app running through AWS on one of their EC2 servers, and I'd like it to be able to send emails when users register. I'm just wondering what is the best way to be able to send emails from my web app? I googled around, and I think my options are:

1. Set up my own mail server (never done this before)
2. Use Amazon's Simple Email Service
3. Somehow connect to the email server that my web hosting provided, and send emails from there. (Not sure if this is possible)

Has anyone ever tried either of these methods, and could comment on the pros/cons? Or perhaps there is another method?

I should mention that I'm running it on a Windows server, and not Linux.

Answer (score 1):

AWS provides Simple Email Service which enables developers to send emails using either API or SMTP. You dont have to take the pain of the setting up the email server for your self. Let me know what platform are you using or you are into, so that I can suggest something. PHP Ruby and Java, I guess most of the platforms with email sending libraries or gems, just can just plug it and and use the required credentials like API ket or SMTP user name and password. Its quite easy to achieve this.If you are bound with marketing stuffs to generate reports, then you can integrate your email sending module with mail chimp or send grid, which are widely used